# Adding SimpleCmsBundle to my existing Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-cmf

For a client I've nearly finished a project, build in Symfony 2.8. The client asked me to add some extra CMS functionality, so he could do some basic page editing himself, like adding/editing pages and menus.

I'm not familiar with Symfony CMF, but as I figured out, just installing the SimpleCmsBundle would be sufficient for now. As the documentation claims, it should be easy to install, but I still get error. Here are the steps I took:

- Adding the package to composer and instantiated the bundles in de kernel. Like said at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/simple_cms/introduction.html#installation.
- Running `composer update` produced the following error:

  ```
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.3.4 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.3.3 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.3.2 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.3.1 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.3.0 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.2.4 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.2.3 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.2.2 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.2.1 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.2.0 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.1.2 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.1.1 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.1.0 requires phpcr/phpcr-implementation 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
  - symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle 1.3.0 requires doctrine/phpcr-bundle ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/phpcr-bundle[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4].
  - Installation request for symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle 1.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle[1.3.0].
  ```
- After some searching I found out I was missing a PHPCR implementation: https://github.com/symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle/issues/142. So I installed `jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal`
- Now running `composer update` will produce:

  ```
  You have requested a non-existent parameter "Could not determine the Doctrine manager. Either Doctrine is not configured or a bundle is misconfigured.".
  ```

And now I'm stuck, because this error barely gives me results on Google. Apparently I'm the only one who gets this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for doctrine dbal, you need the doctrine bundle as well, to configure the postgres/mysql connection to use. are you using that?

Comment: It's just a standard Symfony 2.8 install, so `doctrine/orm` and `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` are installed and configured by default.

Comment: can you try finding where in the code this exception is raised? i can't find it in the cmf sandbox vendor folder.